# Hibernate throws error (Detached entity) while trying to retrieve data

Tags: java, hibernate, mapping, orika

While trying to update entity I'm first retrieving it from the database, then I'm mapping the TO from frontend on it using Orika Mapper.
Then I'm trying to retrieve some data not related to this entity using 'JpaRepository' and `findAllByOrderByCode` method. And while this operation I'm getting a strange error saying that: "An unexpected exception occurred: detached entity passed to persist:".
And this error refers not to the basic field from the entity but to the object from the collection from this entity.
Summarize: 
I have entity A which have bidirectional mapping One to Many to the entity B:

```
class A {
List<B> b;
}
```

then I want to update whole A with an object from frontend which I mapped using Orika Mapper.
And while trying to get some data I have an error.

I found that Orika by default makes a deep copy for collections so  `entityA = customsClearanceOrderRepository.findById(requestTo.getId());`
entityA which has List of entitiesB and which are tracked and included in persistence context is replaced with a deep copy of them so they have another address and it means their aren't any longer tracked by Hibernate. 
So I tried to map those collections by myself, to just update the fields and not create a new object and then the problem has gone.

Everything would be fine but when I removed this line `List<SthTo> all = someRefersToDb.findAllByOrderByCode(); // error appears here`
then the problem also doesn't exist, even that I'm again using orika which makes this deep copy. And I understand that it works fine because of 'saveAndFlush' in fact while updating makes `EntityManager.merge(entity)` and the problem with another address for entities is not a problem for that (cause it copies not tracked object into persistence context).

```
entityA = entityARepository.findById(requestTo.getId());
entityAMapper.map(requestTo, entityA);
List<SthTo> all = someRefersToDb.findAllByOrderByCode(); // error appears here
EntityA entityASaved = entityARepository.saveAndFlush(entityA);
```

So I want to know what's going on here: `someRefersToDb.findAllByOrderByCode();`
Is there some kind of checking the state of the entityA?
Everything is by default, I mean there is no magical `@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)` or sth like this.

Answer (score 0):

I know why!

Hibernate while running `someRefersToDb.findAllByOrderByCode();`
in fact, call also `session.flush()` which is used to synchronize session data with the database. And since Orika changed the addresses of entities their aren't any longer a part of the persistence context and the synchronization fails.